# Call event outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to call `change` WHICH IS IN `MYSELECT` in `$(document).on('click', '.changeSetting', function(e)` ..I changed dropdown value but it doesnot call `change` event..it just set a value..Is there something missing or any mistake?

`<i className="fa fa-pencil changeSetting" title="Change control"></i>`

```
let addOptionClick = 0;
            var MySelect = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function() {
                    return {
                        label: '' ,
                        options:  ['text', 'text', 'text']
                    }
                },
                change: function(event) {
                    this.state.label = '';
                    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  
                    addOptionClick = 0;
                    this.setState({options: ['text', 'text', 'text']});
                },                      
                render: function() {                                       
                    return(
                        <div>
                          <p><b>Field type</b></p>
                            <select className="inputControl" id="field_control" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>                        
                                <option value="text" defaultValue>Textbox</option>
                                <option value="number">Number</option>
                                <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                                <option value="radio">Radio</option>
                                <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
                                <option value="select">Dropdown</option>
                                <option value="date">Date</option>
                                <option value="email">Email</option>
                            </select>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div id="selectOption" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                            <p>
                              <b>Choices</b>
                            </p>
                            <div id="SelectChoice" onChange={this.fillSelectOption}>
                                {
                                    this.state.options.map(function(opt, i) {
                                       $('#SelectChoice input').last().focus();
                                       return <input type={ opt } className="inputControl space" key={i} autoFocus/>
                                    })
                                }
                                <i className="fa fa-plus-circle icon add" title="Add another choice" onClick={this.addOption} id="add_choice"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                );
            }, ...



$(document).on('click', '.changeSetting', function(e) {
...
$("#field_control").val("select"); // I AM CHANGING DROPDOWN VALUE BUT DOESNOT CALL `CHANGE` FUNCTION 
$("#field_control").change(); //this also doesn't work..
...
});
```

Comment: you do not have any option with `value="input"` in `"#field_control"` then how can you say it doesn't call?

Comment: @Poonam I changed it..it was something else which was not necessary to write here..

Comment: I'm afraid cleaning this up would need a more or less complete rewrite, and I would recommend having a look at a react tutorial first. I'd also recommend choosing *either* jquery *or* react.

Comment: okie I will..can u just tell me how to call event outside of reactClass just like onchange of select? @ivarni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you ended up having to mix jquery and react like this, and I would not recommend doing it. But if you really need to call functions on a rendered react component from a global context you can store a reference to it after it's been rendered by using the `componentDidMount` callback.

Example using ES6:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.component = this;
  }

  change() {
    document.write('no, really');  
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <h1>Please don't do this</h1>      
    );
  }
}
```

And then accessing functions via the global `window` object like this

```
window.component.change();
```

You will have race conditions. If the component has not mounted yet you will need to wait for it to do so.

Here's an [example](http://jsbin.com/nivowuyejo/1/edit?js,output). I couldn't bring myself to include jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code I hope it will work for you:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.changeSetting', function(e) {
        console.log('Its working');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry..read my question..I want to call `change` which is in reactClass but when I set value to dropdown it doesnot call..